# How does one get Emacs Python interpreter to work properly

Tags: python, emacs

I find the standard Ubuntu Emacs Python interpreter not particularly good to work with. Consider this small program in Emacs:

```
print ['hello'] * 10000
```

with C-c C-p and C-c C-r with the code block marked I get a slow output in the Python interpreter window.

If I try to stop the output with C-x o C-c C-c I get a very slow response with Emacs running with close to 100% load. After some time I get KeyboardInterrupt, but then any input at the Python prompt is terrible slow. This makes Emacs Python close to useless for me to work with.

I wonder if there is any kind of setup I am missing?

Comment: Are you using [**`elpy`**](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki/Features)?

Comment: I can confirm that `Inferior Python mode` displays the output much slower than e.g., `*compilation*` buffer (in both cases, the same command is run).

Comment: @PeterWood I wasn't using elpy. I have tried that now. The output is still fairly slow.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you elaborate on "compilation buffer"? In interactive data analysis I want to execute part of the code, e.g., with elpy C-c C-c. I am not sure how to do that with, e.g., C-u M-x compile RET python test.py RET

Comment: there is nothing to elaborate. `*compilation*` buffer  is just a reference point (same command take different time depending on the mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that Emacs in general slows down when you look at very long lines, lines >= 10,000 characters. There is no easy fix. Emacs was designed as a text editor, where source code rarely goes above 200 lines.

The "solution" is to turn a blind eye to long lines. For example, when running `print ["hello"] * 10000`, you can "look away" by going to the top of the buffer (`M-<`). The command will run much faster, in my experience it went about 10x faster by doing this.

After it's printed out all the text, Emacs is still slow because the line is still in view. A simple way to scroll it out of view is `print "\n" * 50`.

In general, I try to avoid printing long lines. For example, if `print a` happens to print out a lot, I might change it to `print "\n".join(a)` or `print a[:10]`.

Comment: "In general, I try to avoid printing long lines" Yes. However, when working with interactive data analysis Numpy array printing has no problem, e.g., `print numpy.array(["Hello"] * 10000)` and niether has `print pandas.Series(["Hello"] * 10000)`, so I get used to showing variables with no problem.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: related to [long lines](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/598/7205). On `numpy`: compare: `len(repr(numpy.array(["Hello"] * 10000))) == 86`  vs. `len(repr(["Hello"] * 10000)) == 90000` -- you could customize `sys.displayhook`, to limit `repr()` size.

Comment: The `sys.displayhook`looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of @j-f-sebastian about `sys.displayhook` and `repr()` size in the above comment here is a few attempts:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, textwrap
sys.displayhook = lambda value: print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(repr(value), 80))) if type(value) == list else sys.__displayhook__(value)
```

The above wraps lines and is still slow to show data, but after it is shown the prompt is faster to respond.

The below simply limits the output for all types:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.displayhook = lambda value: print(repr(value)[:200])
```

Here is a slightly more informative version (and with a longer output):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.displayhook = lambda value: print(repr(value)) if len(repr(value)) < 1000 else print("%s ..." % repr(value)[:997])
```

To reset:

```
sys.displayhook = sys.__displayhook__
```